# How to use results from asynchronous function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use the results from my asynchronous function inside another function, but it keeps saying the result is undefined.

This is my structure of my calling function:

```
async callingFn() {
    let value = await calledFn();
    console.log(value);
}
```

This is the structure of the function I'm calling:

```
calledFn() {
    this.myService.getHttpResponse().subscribe(
        (resp: any) => {
            var values = JSON.parse(resp);
            console.log(values);
            return values;
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );
}
```

When I log values in calledFn, the result is as expected. However, when I log the return value of calledFn in callingFn, it returns undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning from the `calledFn`. The subscription method is returning though.`return` the http service call

```js
calledFn() {
  return this.myService.getHttpResponse().subscribe(
    (resp: any) => {
      var values = JSON.parse(resp);
      console.log(values);
      return values;
    },
    error => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}
```